# in local fonts are working in a html file as good while make it live some words in page will automatically changed as symbols

Tags: html, fonts

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
    src: url('font/Gotham-Bold.woff');
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Book';
    src: url('font/Gotham-Book.ttf');
    }
```

fonts are taken but some words are changed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aPfq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your `<head>` section. It assures that special symbols are encoded the right way.